# How do I serialize a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to make a Configuration Data Manager. This would allow multiple services to store and access configuration data that is common to all of them. 
For the purposes of the Manager, I've decided to create a configuration class object - basically what every configuration data entry would look like:
Name, type, and value.

In the object these would all be strings that discribe the configuration data object itself. Once it has gotten this data from its database as strings, it would put it into this configuration object.

Then, I want it to send it through WCF to its destination. BUT, I don't want to send a serialized version of the configuration object, but rather a serialized version of the object *discribed* by the configuration object.

The reason I'd like to do this is so that

1. The Data Manager does not need to know anything about the configuration data.
2. So I can add configuration objects easily without changing the service. Of course, I should be able to do all of the CRUD operations, not just read.

Summary:
Input: string of name, type and value

Output: Serialized output of the object; the object itself is "type name = value"

Questions:

1. Is this a good method for storing and accessing the data?
2. How can I/can I serialize in this manner?
3. What would the function prototype of a getConfigurationData method look like?

I have decided to go in a different direction, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you actually the first person to need to solve these problems? If not, then you'll likely find that it has already been solved, perhaps even by Microsoft, perhaps even in .NET. In other words, "what's wrong with the .NET configuration system that's been in  use for the past ten years?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good method for storing and accessing the data?

That is difficult to answer, the best I can give you is both a "yes" and a "No".  Yes, It's not a bad idea to isolate the serialization/rehydration of this data.... and No, I don't really care much for the way you describe doing it.  I'm not sure I would want it stored in text unless I plan on editing it by hand, and if I'm editing it by hand, I'm not sure I'd want it in a database.  It could be done; just not sure you're really on the right track yet.

> How can I/can I serialize in this manner?

Don't build your own, never that.  Use a well-known format that already exists.  Either XML or JSON will serve for hand-editable, or there are several binary formats (BSON, protobuffers) if you do not need to be able to edit it.

> What would the function prototype of a getConfigurationData method look like?

I would first break-down the 'general' aka common configuration into a seperate call from the service specific configuration.  This enables getConfigurationData to simply return a rich type for common information.  Then either add a extra param and property for service specific data, or add another method.  As an example:

```
[DataContract]
public class ConfigurationInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo;
    ...
    // This string is a json/xml blob specific to the 'svcType' parameter
    [DataMember]
    public string ServiceConfig;
}

[DataContract]
public interface IServiceHost
{
    ConfigurationInfo GetConfigurationData(string svcType);
}
```

Obviously you place a little burden on the caller to parse the 'ServiceConfig'; however, your server can treat it as an opaque string value.  It's only job is to associate it with the appropriate svcType and store/fetch the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
1. I'd much rather store it as the object itself, but then wouldn't the database have to know the object's type? Or is there some generic method I can create to fetch it? (As I should've mentioned earlier, I'm new to C Sharp).
2. I planned on using XML, I just didn't (and don't) know how to go about telling it to serialize the object that is discribed by my custom configuration object. If instead, I have the object itself, it is straight forward to send it on. But, I'd need a abstract way of doing it.